# String Manipulation and System Call in C

Tags: c, string

I'm a C amateur, and I'm having trouble manipulating strings in C. The objective is to add the current `pid` to a base string, then call it with `system(system_call)`. I have the following:

```
char system_call[100] = "top -p "
char pid_string[30];

//quite a bit of other code

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    sprintf(pid_string,"%d",pid);
    strcat(system_call,pid_string);

    printf(system_call); //prints what I expect; something like 'top -p 5580'
    system(system_call); //doesn't work
}
```

The `system` call simply gives `sh: system: not found`. I'm sure people good with C will know the problem instantly. I thought maybe the trailing 0 after strings in C had something to do with it, but I'm too terrible at C to recognize it or know what to do about it. I also tried `system("%s",system_call)` but `system` only takes one argument. Is there something wrong with my memory allocation? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you're posting the real code. *sh: system: not found* sounds very fishy.

Comment: You have also forgot to `return 0;`

Comment: Yeah, and printf(system_call) isn't going to work in standard C. It should be printf("%s", system_call).

Comment: printf(system_call) should work as long as there are no format specifiers in "system_call" like %d

Comment: Duh. Ole, you are correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The variable pid is not given a value before use in the sprintf.

Comment: `top(1)` should run anyway.

Comment: It does in my code, I just forgot to type it over. Typing error, because I'm running in VirtualBox and can't copy and paste because the version of Ubuntu I have to run doesn't support guest additions. Edited now.

Comment: @cnicular True. Maybe trying it with system call set to "which top" would help?

Answer (score 2):

Cant see any problem with your string construction, maybe the problem is that "system" itself does not work for some reason on your system :-), or "top" is not acessible

Comment: And even if it works, `top -p <PID>` is blocking, and `system()` waits for a process completion, so here is when things would get stuck forever.

Comment: Try calling system(NULL) and check the return value. maybe there is something misconfigured in your build environment. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/